# Is there a way to programmatically root/unroot an android device?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am trying to program an app that disguises my android smartphone as a different Bluetooth device, such as a speaker, so I can play around with my computer's drivers. However, I heard that in order to disguise my phone as a different device, I have to root it. Is there a way to programmatically root an android device?

Comment: `Is there a way to programmatically root an android device?` **NO**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No way to root android phone with android studio.
Only Genymotion emulators are simulated root device which you can use it.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Technically, you can use the terminal of Android Studio to root your device, but Android Studio is not required